# Is there an extension of host to host ipsec to a many-many configuration?

Tags: ipsec, openswan, x509, fedora-21

Having a typical host to host transport mode  ipsec configuration,

```
conn appserver01-to-swift01
    leftid=@appserver01.server.com
    left=10.133.176.246
    leftrsasigkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    rightid=@swift01.server.com
    right=10.133.176.111
    authby=rsasig
    rightrsasigkey=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
    # load and initiate automatically
    auto=start
```

Is there a way to make this a many to one/many to many connection? 
i have multiple hosts on the same lan and i was using this to get 
encrypted traffic  between the two hosts,  if i add more hosts, will i need
to add more host to host or is it possible to do:

```
conn mytunnel
     left=192.168.56.120
     leftcert=leftcert.pem
     right=%any
     rightrsasigkey=%cert
     rightca="C=KE, O=Mycompany, OU=mydepartment, CN=*"
     auto=add
```

using certificate authentication? 
i tried something like this but right says

```
We cannot identify ourselves with either end of this connection.
```

and left says:

```
 cannot initiate connection without knowing peer IP address
```

from some documentation i saw (see [right=%any](http://www.natecarlson.com/2006/07/10/configuring-an-ipsec-tunnel-with-openswan-and-l2tpd/#casetup)), i  thought it was possible, but after trying and failing, im thinking its not posssible, 
[redhat](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Security_Guide/Host-To-Host_VPN_Using_Openswan.html),   so is it possible to have the single configuration accept 
any client that presents a valid x.509 certificate regardless of its ip address? all addresses are  private and all machines are pretty much equivalent.

a similar question has been asked before on some mailing list, but i could not find any public reply to it  (lists .openswan. org /pipermail/users/2015-March/023294.html)